# Set different image for small device and for large devices

Tags: html, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I need to put different images for small device and for large device. I tried to solve it with media query but without any success.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="small-12 large-4 columns" id="stickSlider"> <br>
        <a href="#" id="leftSliderImage"></a>
  </div>
```

in css file:

```
#leftSliderImage { background-image: url('img/leftSlider.gif');  width: 324px;  height:395}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) 
{
    #leftSliderImage { background-image: url('img/smartLeftSlider.png'); width: 543px; height:224px;} 
}
```

p.s: I have another same problem in button : I need to put different button image to each device , How can i do this?

Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`
 in the `<head>` of your HTML. [Here's a working demo](http://jsbin.com/acujef/1/edit)